# Solve this integral $ \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\frac{i}{2} \left( n - m \right)x} \cos(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I am supposed to calculate the integrals

$$ \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\frac{i}{2} \left( n - m \right)x} \cos(x) dx$$ and

$$ \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\frac{i}{2} \left( n - m \right)x} \cos^2(x) dx$$

for odd integers $n,m.$ Does anybody know if an analytical result is possible cause I need the actual result? I am a biologist and therefore don't know any integration techniques at all (unless knowing the antiderivative, which I don't in this case)

I hope my question is clear to you.

Comment: Though this doesn't really answer your question, a useful website for integration is: http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Answer (score 0):

### Euler's Formula

First of all you can use Euler's formula to convert the exponential. I am assuming the "i" is the imaginary number. This evaluates to:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \int_0^{2\pi} [\cos([n-m]\cdot \frac{x}{2}) + i\cdot \sin([n-m]\cdot \frac{x}{2})]\cdot \cos(x) dx $$

You can then continue integrating using the integral of a sum is the sum of integrals:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}[\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(\frac{[n-m]\cdot x}{2})\cdot \cos(x) dx + \int_0^{2\pi}i\cdot \sin(\frac{[n-m]\cdot x}{2})\cdot \cos(x) dx]$$

Now you can use separation of variables and a some other techniques to continue integration. I assume that you are asking for a method of making it simpler and Euler's identity is key here.

#### Answer for first sum

including the prefixed 1/(2pi):
$$(m\cdot \sin(\pi\cdot m)\cdot \cos(\pi\cdot n)-n\cdot \sin(\pi\cdot m)\cdot \cos(\pi\cdot n)-m\cdot \cos(\pi\cdot m)\cdot \sin(\pi\cdot n)+n\cdot \cos(\pi\cdot m)\cdot \sin(\pi\cdot n))/((m^2-2\cdot m\cdot n+n^2-4)\cdot\pi) $$

Is the solution for the first part. I am assuming you would like to perform the integration yourself and check the answer for correctness. The second sum is a little harder.

#### 3 Factors of Trigonometry

For the second integral; you have a product of 3 factors of trigonometric functions. This allows you to quite easily integrate using identities as: $$\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$$
in conjunction with the substitution:
$$ u = \cos(x) $$

#### What To Search For

If you would like to know more, then you can try to google trigonometric identities (all of which can be derived from De Moivre's formula, Euler's formula, and the Pythagorean theorem). You may also want to search for the substitution and the "integration by parts" method.

#### Answer

Yes. There is an analytical result. For both integrals, over the range requested. Here is the full first integral:

$$i\cdot \sin(\pi \cdot m)\cdot \sin(\pi \cdot n)+i\cdot \cos(\pi \cdot m)\cdot \cos(\pi \cdot n)+\sin(\pi \cdot m)\cdot \cos(\pi \cdot n)-\cos(\pi \cdot m)\cdot \sin(\pi \cdot n)-i)\cdot (-n+m)/((m-n+2)\cdot (m-n-2)\cdot \pi$$

Second Integral:
$$(i\cdot \sin(\pi \cdot m)\cdot \sin(\pi \cdot n)+i\cdot \cos(\pi \cdot m)\cdot \cos(\pi \cdot n)+\sin(\pi \cdot m)\cdot \cos(\pi \cdot n)-\cos(\pi \cdot m)\cdot \sin(\pi \cdot n)-i)\cdot (m^2-2\cdot m\cdot n+n^2-8)/((m-n+4)\cdot (m-n-4)\cdot (-n+m)\cdot \pi) $$

Comment: do you mind giving me the answer?

Comment: If I haven't made a mistake; here is the first integral. Working on the second one. I highly suggest you use a tool as  Mathematica/Maple/Wolfram to do integrals for you.

Comment: @MrVirus Both integrals are added. You should edit your question to include a request for the actual formulae; as I think your question was only whether or not analytical solutions exist.

Comment: @BourgonAries apparently there are some problems with the brackets in your equation, would you mind checking them again?

Comment: @MrVirus I am assuming you referred to the last equation. The ending parentheses were cut off.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

I would say: $\cos x = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \int e^{\frac{i}{2} ( n - m)x} \cos(x)\, dx=\frac{1}{2}\int e^{\frac{i}{2}( n - m )x} (e^{ix}+e^{-ix}) \,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int e^{\frac{i}{2}( n - m )x} (e^{ix}+e^{-ix}) \,dx=$

$\displaystyle=\frac{1}{2}\int \left(e^{\frac{i}{2}( n - m +2)x} + e^{\frac{i}{2}( n - m -2)x}\right) \,dx=\frac{e^{\frac{i}{2}( n - m +2)x}}{i( n - m +2)}+\frac{e^{\frac{i}{2}( n - m -2)x}}{ i(n - m -2)}+C$

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\frac{i}{2} ( n - m)x} \cos(x) dx=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \left[\frac{e^{\frac{i}{2}( n - m +2)x}}{ i(n - m +2)}+\frac{e^{\frac{i}{2}( n - m -2)x}}{ i(n - m -2)}\right]_{0}^{2\pi}=\cdots$

A similar second integral.

So the analytical solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

A standard technique is the so called *integration by parts*, which is sometimes useful in order to integrate a product of functions 
$$\int_a^b f_1(x)f_2(x)dx.$$

**Integration by parts**
$$(f(x)\cdot g(x))' = f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$$
hence 
$$\int_a^bf'(x)g(x)dx = \int_a^b (f(x)\cdot g(x))' dx - \int_a^b f(x)\cdot g'(x)dx= \\f(x)g(x)\big|_a^b-\int_a^b f(x)\cdot g'(x)dx$$

In the first case of yours this will work fine, because $e^{ax}$ have a nice integral, while $\cos x$ has a nice derivative. When you do the calculation you will need to integrate twice in order to reach a simple equation.

For the second problem, first add up the trigonometric identities 
$$\cos(2x) = \cos^2x-\sin^2x$$ 
and 
$$1 = \cos^2x+\sin^2x$$ 
in order to reach
$$\cos^2x = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(2x) + 1),$$
then the second problem reduces to something similar to the first one.

Comment: By the way, you should be a bit careful when $m=n$.